# ReplaceAll the ImageView in FrameLayout

Tags: android

There are a FrameLayout and a Button,I want to add 6 ImageView onto the FrameLayout,and replaceall the 6 ImageView with other 6 ImageView when I click the Button.Thus the FrameLayout may display 12 ImageView together.(I use the Universal_ImageLoader to load Image to ImageView).How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try to describe your problem in more details. This way is more likely to get the correct answer. Also you can post the code you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the images programmatically (not in xml),you dont need to have 12 image views.

for example set an on click listener for your button,so when you click it, you set a new image to the ImageView:

```
image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.myPic1);
                 image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.myPic2);
                 image3.setImageResource(R.drawable.myPic3);
                 image4.setImageResource(R.drawable.myPic4);
                 image5.setImageResource(R.drawable.myPic5);
                 image6.setImageResource(R.drawable.myPic6);
             }
         });
```

the `setImageResource` method sets a new picture on the ImageView its given (the imageviews here are image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6 ).

now we have put this method inside onClick so whenever you click your button all 6 of your images will change to the image you chose (in my example the images i chose are myPic1, myPic2, myPic3, myPic4, myPic5, myPic6 )

this way you would have replaced all the 6 ImageViews with other 6 ImageViews with a click of a Button like you wanted

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you describe it in detail？

Comment: I think i didnt understand your question correctly,
when you press the button you WANT to add 6 more pictures to the view? so you'd have 12 in total?

Comment: I want to display 6 pictures once，and pre pictures should be removed.

Comment: i explained the answer in more detail, please check it :)